# java.io.NotSerializableException with Spark Streaming Checkpoint enabled

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have enabled checkpointing in my spark streaming application and encounter this error on a class that is downloaded as a dependency.

With no checkpointing the application works great.

Error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.module.paranamer.shaded.CachingParanamer
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: com.fasterxml.jackson.module.paranamer.shaded.CachingParanamer, value: com.fasterxml.jackson.module.paranamer.shaded.CachingParanamer@46c7c593)
    - field (class: com.fasterxml.jackson.module.paranamer.ParanamerAnnotationIntrospector, name: _paranamer, type: interface com.fasterxml.jackson.module.paranamer.shaded.Paranamer)
    - object (class com.fasterxml.jackson.module.paranamer.ParanamerAnnotationIntrospector, com.fasterxml.jackson.module.paranamer.ParanamerAnnotationIntrospector@39d62e47)
    - field (class: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotationIntrospectorPair, name: _secondary, type: class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.AnnotationIntrospector)
    - object (class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotationIntrospectorPair, com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotationIntrospectorPair@7a925ac4)
    - field (class: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotationIntrospectorPair, name: _primary, type: class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.AnnotationIntrospector)
    - object (class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotationIntrospectorPair, com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotationIntrospectorPair@203b98cf)
    - field (class: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.BaseSettings, name: _annotationIntrospector, type: class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.AnnotationIntrospector)
    - object (class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.BaseSettings, com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.BaseSettings@78c34153)
    - field (class: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.MapperConfig, name: _base, type: class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.BaseSettings)
    - object (class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationConfig, com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationConfig@2df0a4c3)
    - field (class: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper, name: _deserializationConfig, type: class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationConfig)
    - object (class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper, com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper@2db07651)
```

I am not sure how to extend this class as serializable as its a maven dependency. I am using v2.6.0 of the jackson core in my pom.xml. If I try to use a newer version of Jackson core I am getting Incompatible Jackson version exception.

Code

```
liveRecordStream
      .foreachRDD(newRDD => {
        if (!newRDD.isEmpty()) {
          val cacheRDD = newRDD.cache()
          val updTempTables = tempTableView(t2s, stgDFMap, cacheRDD)
          val rdd = updatestgDFMap(stgDFMap, cacheRDD)
          persistStgTable(stgDFMap)
          dfMap
            .filter(entry => updTempTables.contains(entry._2))
            .map(spark.sql)
            .foreach( df => writeToES(writer, df))

          cacheRDD.unpersist()
        }
      }
```

The issue is happening only if a method call happens inside  `foreachRDD` like `tempTableView` in this case.

tempTableView

```
def tempTableView(t2s: Map[String, StructType], stgDFMap: Map[String, DataFrame], cacheRDD: RDD[cacheRDD]): Set[String] = {
    stgDFMap.keys.filter { table =>
      val tRDD = cacheRDD
        .filter(r => r.Name == table)
        .map(r => r.values)
         val tDF = spark.createDataFrame(tRDD, tableNameToSchema(table))
      if (!tRDD.isEmpty()) {
        val tName = s"temp_$table"
        tDF.createOrReplaceTempView(tName)
      }
      !tRDD.isEmpty()
    }.toSet
  }
```

Any help is appreciated. Not sure how to debug this and fix the issue.

Comment: Can you try to put **"tempTableView(t2s, stgDFMap, cacheRDD)"** into a transformation like map or filter? Because transformations are executed in workers, which don't have to transfer from driver to work by serializing.

Answer (score 5):

From the code snippet you had shared, I don't see where the `jackson` library is invoked. However, `NotSerializableException` usually happens when you try to send an object which doesn't implement `Serializable` interface over wire.

And Spark is distributed processing engine, meaning it works this way: There is a driver and multiple executors across nodes. Only the part of code that is needed to be computed is sent by the `driver` to the `executors` (over wire). Spark transformations happen in that way i.e. across multiple nodes and if you try pass an instance of a class, which doesn't implement `serializable` interface, to such code blocks (the block that executes across nodes), it will throw `NotSerializableException`.

Ex:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
   val gson: Gson = new Gson()

   val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]")
   val spark = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).getOrCreate()
   val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq("0","1"))

   val something = rdd.map(str => {
     gson.toJson(str)
   })

   something.foreach(println)
   spark.close()
}
```

This code block will throw `NotSerializableException` because we are sending an instance of `Gson` to a distributed function. `map` is a Spark transformation operation so it will execute on executors. The following will work:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

   val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]")
   val spark = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).getOrCreate()
   val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq("0","1"))

   val something = rdd.map(str => {
     val gson: Gson = new Gson()
     gson.toJson(str)
   })

   something.foreach(println)
   spark.close()
}
```

Reason why the above will work is, we are instantiating `Gson` within a transformation, so it will be instantiated at the executor, meaning it won't be sent from the driver program over the wire so no serialization is needed.

Comment: Thank you for a clear explanantion on how it functions. Why does this behavior occur only when checkpointing is enabled?

Comment: Great explanation. It's the clearest and synthetic I found.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with `jackson` `objectMapper` that was trying to be serialized. `objectMapper` should not be serialized. Fixed this by adding `@transient val objMapper = new ObjectMapper...`