# org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable while writing stream to blob store

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, serialization, jackson

I have been going through a lot of similar posts but I am not able to understand the reason here. I had the whole code working.

I only added the following code later:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.{DeserializationFeature, ObjectMapper}
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper
def toJson(value: Map[Symbol, Any]): String = {
    toJson(value map { case (k,v) => k.name -> v})
}
def toJson(value: Any): String = {
    mapper.writeValueAsString(value)
}
def toMap[V](json:String)(implicit m: Manifest[V]): Map[String, Any] = fromJson[Map[String,Any]](json)
def fromJson[T](json: String)(implicit m : Manifest[T]): T = {
    mapper.readValue[T](json)
}
val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
```

and now when i execute the following writestream cell in notebook:

```
data.writeStream
    .option("checkpointLocation", _checkpointLocation)
    .format("avro")
    .partitionBy("Date", "Hour")
    .option("path",  _containerPath)
    .start()
```

I am getting this error:

```
    org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:196)
    Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:403)
    Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.fasterxml.jackson.module.paranamer.shaded.CachingParanamer
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: com.fasterxml.jackson.module.paranamer.shaded.CachingParanamer, value: com.fasterxml.jackson.module.paranamer.shaded.CachingParanamer@660424b3)
    - field (class: com.fasterxml.jackson.module.paranamer.ParanamerAnnotationIntrospector, name: _paranamer, type: interface com.fasterxml.jackson.module.paranamer.shaded.Paranamer)
```

Can anyone help me understand what could be going wrong here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the culrpit

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.{DeserializationFeature, ObjectMapper}
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper
def toJson(value: Map[Symbol, Any]): String = {
    toJson(value map { case (k,v) => k.name -> v})
}
def toJson(value: Any): String = {
    mapper.writeValueAsString(value)
}
def toMap[V](json:String)(implicit m: Manifest[V]): Map[String, Any] = fromJson[Map[String,Any]](json)
def fromJson[T](json: String)(implicit m : Manifest[T]): T = {
    mapper.readValue[T](json)
}
val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
```

that means that you json parser is not serializable try to implement serializable for your json class/object

try using [Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49766950/647053) or

```
class Jsonparser extends serializable
```

would be the solution for this.

see how task not serialzable happens [here- org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-tips-and-tricks-sparkexception-task-not-serializable.html)

Answer (score 1):

This answer might be coming too late for you, but hopefully it can help some others.

You don't have to give up and switch to Gson. I prefer the jackson parser as it is what spark used under-the-covers for spark.read.json() and doesn't require us to grab external tools. It looks like we both use (com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jsonSchema:2.9.6) which allows direct deserialization of json in scala.

Anyways, there are actually a couple of different ways to bypass this specific restriction. I prefer to keep kryo-serialization, so my recommendation is to wrap with a class. I usually access this in as an automatic broadcast variable and instantiate within a mapPartitions on an dataframe to rdd method. If I am doing an on-the-fly streaming transformation I use foreachBatch. My answer is provided in a non-streaming format to make it more useful to others.

```scala
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.{DeserializationFeature, ObjectMapper}
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule

class FastJson extends Serializable {
   val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
   mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
   mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
 
   def toJson(value: Map[Symbol, Any]): String = {
     toJson(value map { case (k,v) => k.name -> v})
   }
 
   def toJson(value: Any): String = {
     mapper.writeValueAsString(value)
   }
 
   def toMap[V](json:String)(implicit m: Manifest[V]) = fromJson[Map[String,V]](json)
 
   def fromJson[T](json: String)(implicit m : Manifest[T]): T = {
     mapper.readValue[T](json)
      }
}
```

```scala
val sample_records = Array("""{"id":"1c589374-4a1f-11ea-976f-02423e9c355b","offset":"1004468136126","occurred":"2020-02-08T02:59:11.546Z","processed":"2020-02-08T03:00:07.078Z","device":{"that":"57bee599-8fa5-4e98-af88-17367b2dc327"}}""",
                           """{"id" : "8d4de2f2-fdf8-11ea-a111-02424cf4aed7","offset" : "1005930726202","occurred":"2020-09-23T23:57:27.211Z","processed":"2020-09-23T23:57:35.390Z","device" : {"this":"123456"}}""")
val sample_df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(sample_records).toDF
sample_df.printSchema
println(s"count : ${sample_df.count()}")
```

> sample_records: Array[String] = Array({"id":"1c589374-4a1f-11ea-976f-02423e9c355b","offset":"1004468136126","occurred":"2020-02-08T02:59:11.546Z","processed":"2020-02-08T03:00:07.078Z","device":{"that":"57bee599-8fa5-4e98-af88-17367b2dc327"}}, {"id" : "8d4de2f2-fdf8-11ea-a111-02424cf4aed7","offset" : "1005930726202","occurred":"2020-09-23T23:57:27.211Z","processed":"2020-09-23T23:57:35.390Z","device" : {"this":"123456"}})
> sample_df: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [value: string]
> root
> |-- value: string (nullable = true)
> count : 2

```scala
val json_action_df = sample_df.rdd.mapPartitions(partition => {
    val fastJson = new FastJson
    val partition_results = partition.map(row => {
        val stringified_row = row.getAs[String]("value")
        val swapJsonMap = fastJson.fromJson[Map[String, Any]](stringified_row)
        val id_field = swapJsonMap.get("id").getOrElse("")
        id_field.asInstanceOf[String]
    })
    partition_results.toIterator
}).toDF("id")
```

```scala
json_action_df.show(10, false)
```

+------------------------------------+
|id                                  |
+------------------------------------+
|1c589374-4a1f-11ea-976f-02423e9c355b|
|8d4de2f2-fdf8-11ea-a111-02424cf4aed7|
+------------------------------------+